# Azure blob file got corrupted post uploading file using UploadFromStreamAsync

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I tried below code to upload file to azure blob container but uploaded file got corrupted.

```
 public async void UploadFile(Stream memoryStream, string fileName, string containerName)
    {
        try
        {
             memoryStream.Position = 0;
            CloudBlockBlob file = GetBlockBlobContainer(containerName).GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            file.Metadata["FileType"] = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            file.Metadata["Name"] = fileName;
           await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve it.

Unable to open excel file which was uploaded to blob using above code.

**Error:**

[image]

```
     Stream streamData= ConvertDataSetToByteArray(sourceTable); // sourceTable is the DataTable
                     streamData.Position = 0;

UploadFile(streamData,'ABCD.xlsx','sampleBlobContainer'); //calling logic to upload stream to blob

       private Stream ConvertDataSetToByteArray(DataTable dataTable)
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => (field.ToString()));
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                var myByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

                var streamData = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);

                return streamData;
            }
```

Comment: What's the meaning when your are saying the file has got corrupted? Is it not readable or something? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please check whether the part of your memorystream conversion is wrong.

Comment: What does `got corrupted` mean? Where does the MemoryStream come from and what does it contain? Are you sure its contents are OK? If you upload corrupted data the result will be a corrupted file.

Comment: Updated question with corrupted file screenshot

Comment: @chandrasekhar Do you mean that you upload a .xlsx file to azure blob storage but it broken after download?

Comment: Actually I have DataTable. I have converted it to stream. I uploaded  this stream as xlsx file to blob using above code.I have provided file name as ABCD.xlsx, When I download and open uploaded file, I got above error.

Comment: @chandrasekhar can you show about the method that you used to turn file to stream?

Comment: I suspect you use the wrong method to turn file to stream because the .xlsx file didn't be broken on my side.

Comment: added additional code

Comment: To me it looks like you're creating a .csv file and uploading it as an xlsx. I think excel only complains because it's thinking it's opening an xlsx and that's not what is in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above creates a .csv file, not an .xlsx file. You can easily test this out by creating something similar to what your code builds, e.g.:

[image: test.txt contents]

Then if you rename it to .xlsx, to replicate what you do, you get:

[image: excel result for opening text.xlsx]

You have two solutions:

1. You either need to build an actual .xlsx file, you can do this with the https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus package for example

or

2. You need to save your file as a .csv, because that's what it really is.

The fact the you upload it to azure blob storage is completely irrelevant here - there's no issue with the upload.

Comment: Instead of creating csv from DataTable stream, can't we directly create xlsx file in blob without using  any packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stream is instantiated outside this method I assume the file is handled there and added to the stream, however, here you are returning the position of the stream to 0, thus invalidating the file.

Comment: I tried adding Position to 0 even at the stream root place, even then facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your method don't have  fatal problems. I guess the part of your Stream conversion has gone wrong.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        public static class Util
        {
            public async static void UploadFile(Stream memoryStream, string fileName, string containerName)
            {
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                var blockBlob = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
                    .GetContainerReference(containerName)
                    .GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Open the file
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\bowmanzh\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx", FileMode.Open);

            //Read the byte[] of File
            byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();

            //turn from byte[] to Stream
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            Util.UploadFile(stream,"Book2.xlsx","test");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH7s3.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure the file got corrupted? Save both the `MemoryStream` contents and the blog to local files and compare them. You could also save the MemoryStream contents to a file and use `UploadFromFileAsync`.

To check for actual corruption you should calculate the content's MD5 hash in advance and compare it with the blob's hash after upload.

To calculate the stream's MD5 hash use [ComputeHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var hasher=MD5.Create();
 memoryStream.Position = 0;
var originalHash=Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(memoryStream));
```

To get the client to calculate an blob has you need to set the [BlobRequestOptions.StoreBlobContentMD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.storeblobcontentmd5?view=azure-dotnet) option while uploading :

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
var options = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            StoreBlobContentMD5 = testMd5
        };
await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream,null,options,null).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

To retrieve and check the uploaded hash use `FetchAttributes` or [FetchAttributesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_FetchAttributesAsync) and compare the [BlobProperties.ContentMD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentmd5?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobProperties_ContentMD5) value with the original :

```
file.FetchAttributes();
var blobHash=file.Properties.ContentMD5;
if (blobHash != originalHash)
{
   //Ouch! Retry perhaps?
}
```